# Maximum SIMD integer multiplications on Ivy Bridge using SSE/AVX?

Tags: c++, vectorization, sse, simd, avx

Would somebody be able to advise me how I can work out the maximum number of 32-bit unsigned integer multiplications I would be able to do concurrently on an Ivy Bridge CPU using SIMD via SSE/AVX?

I understand AVX did have 256-bit registers for multiplication but this was for floating point (AVX2 introduced 256-bit integer registers). Therefore I am not overly sure whether it would be better to use floating-point registers for integer multiplication (if thats even possible)?

In addition, I am unsure whether it matters on just the number of registers, or whether I need to look at the ports of the CPU. Looks like port 0 and port 5 can handle SSE integer ALU?

Comment: you could use double instead. All 32-bit integers are represented exactly by double

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: While that's true, it also takes more space and only 4 fit in an AVX register, completely defeating the purpose.  You can already fit four 32-bit integers in an SSE register.

Comment: Guys I found this example of what I need but its for signed integers, does anyone know how to change it for unsigned? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500766/sse-multiplication-of-4-32-bit-integers

Comment: Signed and unsigned multiplication are the same thing by the way, there's only a difference if you want the upper half as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one `pmulld` = 4 multiplications per clock.

> Therefore I am not overly sure whether it would be better to use floating-point registers for integer multiplication (if thats even possible)?

Nothing like that is possible. You can put 8 integers in an `ymm` register of course, but then you're stuck. The instruction you'd need to do something useful with them is in AVX2.

Comment: There's an Intel intrinsic called _mm_mul_ps which takes 2x 128-bit array-of-4-ints, multiplies them together and uses MULPS. What is the difference with MULPS and PMULLD?

Comment: @user997112 `mulps` multiplies floats, `pmulld` is for integers.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500766/sse-multiplication-of-4-32-bit-integers but they are looking at multiplying signed integers and I would like unsigned. Could you advise how the code would change?

Comment: @user997112 it's based around using `pmuludq` to emulate `pmulld`, but the `ymm` version of that is also `AVX2`, and so is everything else that might be useful. This way of doing it wouldn't even be useful if the 256 bit `vpmuludq` *was* in AVX, it needs two multiplications which undoes the improvement from the doubled width.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here:

- [Can long integer routines benefit from SSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866973/can-long-integer-routines-benefit-from-sse)
- [SSE multiplication of 2 64-bit integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863411/sse-multiplication-of-2-64-bit-integers)

There is no current solution to improve multiplication of long integers with SSE or AVX.