# can someone explain this SSE BigNum comparison?

Tags: sse, simd

If you look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200698/is-it-possible-to-use-sse-v2-to-make-a-128-bit-wide-integer/18673708#18673708), the author manages to create a compact comparison algorithm for 2 integer bignums, stored in 2 SSE registers. I am not following it too well :)

What I did so far:

if `l = a < b = {a[i] < b[i] ? ~0 : 0}` and

```
e = a == b = {a[i] == b[i] ? ~0 : 0}
```

then `a < b == l[3] v e[3]l[2] v e[3]e[2]l[1] v e[3]e[2]e[1]l[0]`

But this does not seem to be what the author is doing. What am I missing? What need is there for a greater than comparison?

Comment: He uses greater-than comparison because it's the only integer compare that's available for SSE.

Comment: But otherwise he calculates less than according to the same formula I use?

Comment: @Mysticial Ahhh, I see, nasty trickery and specific to 64-bit bignums.

Answer (score 0):

I've overlooked than the answer was not generic, but limited to 64-bit bignums, composed out of 32-bit elements. If you have 2 64-bit vectors `a = {a0, a1}`, `b = {b0, b1}`, then the program calculates:

```
a < b = ((a1 < b1) | (a0 < b0)) & ~(a1 > b1)
```

In my question I was aiming at arbitrarily long BigNums, implemented with SSE/AVX registers.